# Basic Installation Needs using InstallShield Express

Tags: express, installshield

Our needs are simple but we can't figure out how to make this happen using InstallShield Express. We want to install our software program along with some templates. We issue frequent updates to the program and don't want the update to overwrite the templates that were installed, only the program files. Here is all we need:

1. One install file that installs new software if it doesn't already exist on the user's system or updates existing software to the latest version if already installed.
2. We don't want the user to have to Uninstall the software before installing the new software when updating.
3. On an update, only replace the program files and not the templates that were installed originally.
4. On an update, recognize the location of previously installed version and update that version.

The Update Paths option in InstallShield seems to be the answer but we can't get it to stop Uninstalling everything before Reinstalling the update.

Can anyone help?

Thanks!

Comment: This may be a question for http://www.superuser.com

Answer (score 0):

Try choosing following option in upgrade view:

> Install setup then remove unneeded files.